# Sharepoint error - configured maximum buffer size 100mb

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, filesize

i have the following issue:
Want to copy xls file from sharepoint to adls via logic apps, but unfortunely receiving the following message (below image):

configured maximum buffer size

So is there any solution to solve this problem?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try and use MS Graph. Put simply, you’ve hit the file size limit.

Answer (score 0):

That file is bigger than the limit ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=consumption%2Cazure-portal#workflow-definition-limits))
[image]

Some tasks support chunking. that SharePoint one does not. Http will do ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#set-up-chunking))
so, you can try using http to invoke graph